# MyBatis + Spring Boot jdbcType (null) combination

Tags: java, spring-boot, mybatis

I'm new with MyBatis but I was trying to do an operation of insert to me database. I have a class PartiticipantsResource and a interface ParticipantsMapper the only operation that don't work for me is the insert: If someone can help me to fix this, I will appreciate it a lot

```
class : ParticipantsMapper

@Mapper
public interface ParticipantsMapper {
    @Select("select * from participant")
    List<Participant> findAll();


    @Insert("insert into participant(name, email, checkedIn, event) values(#{name},#{email},#{checkedIn},#{event})")
    @SelectKey(statement = "SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()", keyProperty = "id",
        before = false, resultType = Long.class)
    void insert(Participant participant);


    @Update("update participant set email=#{email} where name=#{name}")
    void update(Participant participant);


    @Update("delete from participant where email=#{email}")
    void delete(Participant participant);
}
```

My class Participant

```
Entity
public class Participant extends AbstractEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String email;

    private Boolean checkedIn;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    private Event event;

    public Event getEvent() {
        return event;
    }

    public void setEvent(Event event) {
        this.event = event;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Boolean getCheckedIn() {
        return checkedIn;
    }

    public void setCheckedIn(Boolean checkedIn) {
        this.checkedIn = checkedIn;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        return Objects.equals(id,((Participant)obj).id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(id);
    }
    public Long getResourcesId(){
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

and this is the error is about the object (event) that my class participant use

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property 'event'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType (com.example.eventmanagement.entities.Event) : jdbcType (null) combination"


Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-04-11 14:48:49.673 ERROR 11812 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'participantsResource': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'participantsMapper'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'participantsMapper' defined in file [C:\Users\cscacho\IdeaProjects\test_rest\eventmanagement-api\target\classes\com\example\eventmanagement\Mapper\ParticipantsMapper.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Could not find value method on SQL annotation.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property 'event'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType (com.example.eventmanagement.entities.Event) : jdbcType (null) combination.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:587) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:91) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:373) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1344) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:868) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.example.eventmanagement.EventmanagementApiApplication.main(EventmanagementApiApplication.java:18) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'participantsMapper' defined in file [C:\Users\cscacho\IdeaProjects\test_rest\eventmanagement-api\target\classes\com\example\eventmanagement\Mapper\ParticipantsMapper.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Could not find value method on SQL annotation.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property 'event'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType (com.example.eventmanagement.entities.Event) : jdbcType (null) combination.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1710) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:502) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:251) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1065) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:584) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Could not find value method on SQL annotation.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property 'event'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType (com.example.eventmanagement.entities.Event) : jdbcType (null) combination.
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:83) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44) ~[spring-tx-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1769) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1706) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 29 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Could not find value method on SQL annotation.  Cause: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property 'event'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType (com.example.eventmanagement.entities.Event) : jdbcType (null) combination.
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.getSqlSourceFromAnnotations(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:472) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.parseStatement(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:289) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.parse(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:134) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperRegistry.addMapper(MapperRegistry.java:72) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.Configuration.addMapper(Configuration.java:728) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperFactoryBean.checkDaoConfig(MapperFactoryBean.java:80) ~[mybatis-spring-1.3.1.jar:1.3.1]
    ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Type handler was null on parameter mapping for property 'event'. It was either not specified and/or could not be found for the javaType (com.example.eventmanagement.entities.Event) : jdbcType (null) combination.
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.ParameterMapping$Builder.validate(ParameterMapping.java:119) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.mapping.ParameterMapping$Builder.build(ParameterMapping.java:104) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.SqlSourceBuilder$ParameterMappingTokenHandler.buildParameterMapping(SqlSourceBuilder.java:123) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.SqlSourceBuilder$ParameterMappingTokenHandler.handleToken(SqlSourceBuilder.java:67) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.parsing.GenericTokenParser.parse(GenericTokenParser.java:78) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.SqlSourceBuilder.parse(SqlSourceBuilder.java:45) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.defaults.RawSqlSource.<init>(RawSqlSource.java:46) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.scripting.xmltags.XMLLanguageDriver.createSqlSource(XMLLanguageDriver.java:60) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.buildSqlSourceFromStrings(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:482) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    at org.apache.ibatis.builder.annotation.MapperAnnotationBuilder.getSqlSourceFromAnnotations(MapperAnnotationBuilder.java:465) ~[mybatis-3.4.4.jar:3.4.4]
    ... 37 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I created a new class to handler the object and now Spring compiled without error. But when I try to insert a new record show me an error: `There was an unexpected error
nested exception is org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Could not set parameters for mapping: ParameterMapping{......} Cause: org.apache.ibatis.type.TypeException: Error setting non null for parameter #4 with JdbcType OTHER . Try setting a different JdbcType for this parameter or a different configuration property. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid argument value: java.io.NotSerializableException`

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. This is not a forum, but Q&A site. Please update your question (or close this and create new) with the relevant details. Also have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask